# Command failed: tar xzf android-sdk_r20-linux.tgz

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I was trying to build kivy app to android and got this error

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/ali/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK is missing, downloading
# Unpacking Android SDK
# Command failed: tar xzf android-sdk_r20-linux.tgz
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

command

```
$ buildozer android_new debug
```

log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/20850804/

want any details? request in the comments

Comment: `# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2`

Comment: the full log:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/20850804/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

the problem was some google services are not available where i live due to USA sanctions on my country (Sudan) and the returned response is html (not in gzip format).

the solution is to use vpn.

Answer (score 3):

The machine fails to properly download the android SDK.

You can confirm this by checking the md5 sum of the file :

```
wget -O - http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r20-linux.tgz | md5sum
```

This should output : 22a81cf1d4a951c62f71a8758290e9bb

If it doesn't, my first guess would be that you're blocked by some kind of proxy or firewall. A proxy can be configured to limit the maximum size of a a file you're trying to download. Check the logs or contact your sysadmins if you're not the administrator of the machine.

Comment: i know what is the problem see my answer below